# printf("something\n") outputs "something " (additional space) (g++/linux/reading output file with gedit)

Tags: c++, printing, stdout, stdin

I have a simple C++ program that reads `stdin` using `scanf` and returns results to `stdout` using `printf`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, x;
    int f=0, s=0, t=0;

    scanf("%d",&n); scanf("%d",&x);

    for(int index=0; index<n; index++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&f);
        scanf("%d",&s);
        scanf("%d",&t);

        if(x < f)
        {
            printf("first\n");
        }
        else if(x<s)
        {
            printf("second\n");
        }
        else if(x<t)
        {
            printf("third\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("empty\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling with g++ and running under linux. I execute the program using a text file as input, and pipe the output to another text file as follows:

> program < in.txt > out.txt

The problem is that out.txt looks like this:

> result1_
>   result2_
>   result3_
>   ...

Where '_' is an extra space at the end of each line. I am viewing out.txt in gedit.

How can I produce output without the additional space?

My input file looks like this:

> 2 123
>   123 123 123
>   123 234 212

**Edit:** I was able to find a workaround for this issue: `printf("\rfoo");`
Thanks for your input!

Comment: You haven't posted enough code to diagnose the problem.  Where do you print d?

Comment: @David Norman
I have added full source code - thanks for help in advance.

Comment: have you actually viewed it with a hex editor? your text editor may fool you and display the whitespace always

Comment: also, where are you printing the numbers?

Comment: I ran this code with several different input files, each with different formatting, etc. It always produces outputs with no extra space at the end.

Comment: you just have to change your gedit settings from "windows line endings" to "unix line endings" and then it should work

Answer (score 2):

The end of line chars are:

```
System  Hex     Value   Type
Mac     0D      13      CR
DOS     0D 0A   13 10   CR LF
Unix    0A      10      LF
```

For a end of line on each system you can:

```
printf("%c", 13);
printf("%c%c", 13, 10);
printf("%c", 10);
```

You can use this like

```
printf("empty");
printf("%c", 10);
```

Wikipedia Newline article [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the '\n' from your `printf()` statements, and run the code again. If the output file looks like one long word (no spaces), then you know that the only thing being inserted after the text is that '\n'.

I assume that the editor you are using to read the out.txt file just makes it *look* like there is an extra space after the output.

If you are still unsure, you can write a quick program to read in out.txt and determine the ASCII code of each character.

Comment: As you're using Linux, you could us bvim to change the actual byte content of your file - in case it is just the editor giving you the impression there is a space.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it's a little hard to figure this out, as the example program has numerous errors:

```
g++ -o example example.cc
example.cc: In function 'int main()':
example.cc:19: error: 'k' was not declared in this scope
example.cc:22: error: 'o' was not declared in this scope
example.cc:24: error: 'd' was not declared in this scope
make: *** [example] Error 1
```

But it's not going to be your input file; your scanf will be loading whatever you're typing into `int`s.  This example, though:

```
/* scan -- try scanf */
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n ;
    (void) scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("%d\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

produced this result:

```
bash $ ./scan | od -c
42
0000000    4   2  \n                                                    
0000003
```

on Mac OS/X.  Get us a copy of the code you're actually running, and the results of od -c.

Comment: Sorry for the variable declaration errors, you guys are anwsering so fast I was not able to correct this fast enough when I noticed... :)

Answer (score 0):

More information is needed here, as timhon asked, which environment are you working under?  Linux, Windows, Mac?  Also, what text editor are you using which displays these extra spaces?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your space isn't really a space.  Run

```
od -hc out.txt
```

to double check that it is really a space.

Answer (score 0):

First, the code sample you've given doesn't compile as o and d are not defined...

Second, you've probably got whitespace at the end of the line you're reading in from the input file.  Try opening it in vi to see.  Otherwise, you can call a trim function on each line prior to output and be done with it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're looking at the output of the program you expect; this has a syntax error (no ";" after `int n`).

Answer (score 0):

I feel like it's not even close to this, but if you run this on Windows, you'll get \r\n as line terminators, and, maybe, under *nix, under a non-Windows-aware text editor, you'll get \r as a common blank space, since \r is not printable.

Long shot, the best way to test this is using an hexadecimal editor and see the file yourself.